# segfault after changing format string from "%c" to "%02X" in fscanf

Tags: c, cryptography, char, scanf, format-specifiers

So I'm trying to read in a bunch of ciphertexts from a file for a homework assignment. I have the following code:

```
void get_ciphertexts_from_file(unsigned char** ciphertexts){
    unsigned char ch;
    FILE *fpIn;
    int i = 0;
    int cur_text = 0;
    int r = 0;
   
    fpIn = fopen("ctexts.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(fpIn, "%02X", &ch) != EOF) {
        printf("mk3 %d %d %02x\n", cur_text, i, ch);
        ciphertexts[cur_text][i] = ch;  

        i++;
        if(i == 31) {
            cur_text++;

            if(cur_text >= 7) {
                break;
            }

            i = 0;
            fscanf(fpIn, "%02X", &ch);
        }

    }

    fclose(fpIn);


}
```

the code outputs `mk3 0 0 BB` and then segfaults. It seems that the second call to fscanf in the loop causes the segfault. I have no idea what is going on because it seems like such a simple piece of code.
Wierdly enough, if I change the `"%02X"` format specifier to `"%c"` the code works fine and doesn't segfault. I have no idea why that would happen.

Some other things I know through debugging:

- the return value of the first fscanf call is 1, like it should be if the read was successful
- the if statement is evaluated to false, so the code inside it does not run
- "BB" are the first 2 characters in the file, so I know that the program is opening and reading from the file correctly
- it segfaults even if I comment out the first 2 lines inside the while loop, so adding to the ciphertexts array does not cause the segfault, and the debug printf does not cause the segfault

I imagine it must have something to do with the `ch` variable, but I don't know what I could be doing wrong. I suppose it's also possible that I corrupted memory somewhere else, but I'm doing the simplest dynamic allocation ever. I will edit this with the rest of my code if someone thinks it's relevant

edit: here is the rest of my code:

```
unsigned char** allocate_ciphertexts_mem() {
    unsigned char** ciphertexts = malloc(7 * sizeof(unsigned char*));

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        ciphertexts[i] = malloc(31);
    }

    return ciphertexts;
}

void free_ciphertexts_mem(unsigned char** ciphertexts){

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        free(ciphertexts[i]);

    }

    free(ciphertexts);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv) {
    unsigned char** ciphertexts = allocate_ciphertexts_mem();

    get_ciphertexts_from_file(ciphertexts);

    for(int text = 0; text < 7; text++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
            printf("%02x", ciphertexts[text][i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }


    free_ciphertexts_mem(ciphertexts);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example (with `main`) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: just edited with the rest of the code!

Comment: Why do you have an extra `fscanf(fpIn, "%02X", &ch);` inside the `if` block?

Comment: *segfault after changing format string from "%c" to "%02X" in fscanf* Just as would be expected.  Based on that, I would say you need `%02hhX`.

Comment: Does your compiler show some warning? If not, enable all of them. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Ask yourself: What parameter type is expected for `scanf("%02x"`? What do you provide?

Comment: You basically lie at your compiler. You promise that you pass the address of an `unsigned int` variable for `%02x` but instead you only pass the address of a `char` variable. That makes `scanf` write 4 bytes into an area where 3 bytes hit something else than the variable you provide. That can corrupt any variable next to `ch`. Maybe your `fpIn`  is dead afterwards. It's undefined behaviour anyway.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I didn't know that `%02x` would read into an int. Using `%02hhx` fixed the problem.